# Storing received notifications in my android app?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications

When i slide a notification it disappears. what i am trying to do is to keep that notification stored in a place in my app so that i can view it anytime. and whenever i tap on it it does the required activity.Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: build a notification with saved data with pending intent , whenever you need

Comment: Simply make it an API call and show them in a recyclerview!